# Web api returning value but client is getting TargetInvocationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, webclient

I have implemented web APIs for my application. While returning simple value from api application is working fine. But if I return a list of objects from entity framework, at Client side application shows TargetInvocationException.

[image: This is My web apiCode from where i am returning list of objects]

[image: Below is client side where i am getting exception]

[image: Full exception details]

Comment: Can you post innerException, where exception is thrown....that will tell more...

Comment: @SSA: sure, i am updating my question with exception details.

Comment: Well that says, there is a problem on remote server (api) 500 internal server error. Are you sure API is returning results? You tried in browser ?

Comment: Capture the traffic between client and server (by using Fiddler or any other similar tool), and post the server response.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev let me let you one more thing. I have tryed this with list of objects not from entity framework. In that case it works fine. But when i use return objects list from EF it gives this error

Comment: @SSA, yes i am sure my api is returning result. I have tryed this with dummy object list.

Comment: Please post the http capture.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev, actually i am not having fiddler now, but if you want traffic capture, that also i will post in sometime.